# How to configure the routeEnhancers in Typo3 9?

Tags: yaml, typo3-9.x

I'm using typo3 9,5 and I'm trying to generate a route from an extension. Everything is working fine until I found that whenever the URL is much the argument of the route will cause an Error

example:

```
testRoute:
type: Extbase
extension: testExtension
plugin: testMain
routes:
  - { routePath: '/test/info/{name}/{period}', _controller: 
    'content::info', _arguments: {'name': 'name','period': 'period'} }
defaultController: 'content::info'
aspects:
  # here we get the needed information for a nice URL for _arguments
  name:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: 'xx'
    routeFieldName: slug
  period:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: 'xx'
    routeFieldName: slug
```

The route is working fine. 
Problem: 
if I have any page with period as a name (testperiod) typo3 try to generate testRoute which i defined

```
   Error
   Parameter "tx_testextension_info__period" for route "tx_testextension_info_0" must 
     match 
    "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

Even if the URL was :
/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxperiod will throw an Error

How can I limit the route for the Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try limiting the effect of a route on a specified page using the argument limitToPages.
Example :

```
  NewsList:
    type: Plugin
    limitToPages: [3]
    routePath: '/{@widget_0/currentPage}'
    namespace: 'tx_news_pi1'
    aspects:
      '@widget_0/currentPage':
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'
```

In this example, my route will only work on the page 3.

Comment: I thought that LimitPages is not working but finally it work thank you very much